# Forcing Systemd to Re-Isolate a Target Unit

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, systemd

My goal is to programmatically re-run the graphical target unit using the `systemctl` command. While I'm aware that I can use `sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target`, this approach doesn't seem to work when the graphical target is already active.

I'm seeking guidance on how to achieve a fresh start of the graphical target unit even if it's currently active.

for example a command to force `systemd` to kills all the target process ( + other ) before it start the graphical again. almost like you have rebooted the system again.

Right now to achieve this i first switch to rescue target and then `isolate` back to graphical. is there any better solution?

Comment: Have you tried just `systemctl stop`-ing the target before isolating it or restarting it? or just use `systemctl restart`?   (on my system, I just run `systemctl restart lightdm` if I want to kill and restart X and all its child processes).  BTW, see `man systemctl` and read the warning there...and also that it says "*Note that this operation is allowed only on units where `AllowIsolate=` is enabled. See `systemd.unit(5)` for details*"

Comment: thank you @cas. i tried `systemctl restart graphical.target`. but it seems it does not kill other process, and only restart the graphical.target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for example a command to force systemd to kills all the target process ( + other ) before it start the graphical again. almost like you have rebooted the system again.

The command for that is `systemctl soft-reboot`, new in v254.

In previous versions: Switch to a minimal target (say, `systemctl rescue` aka `systemctl isolate rescue.target`), wait for sulogin prompt, provide the root password, switch back (`systemctl default`). There is no single-step command, because, well, one wasn't added until v254.

(Alternatively, `systemctl kexec` could do a "kernel reboot" – stopping all processes and services as usual, then launching a new Linux kernel and starting everything again – but skipping the firmware and bootloader, i.e. directly jumping from Linux to Linux. Unfortunately, kexec is a bit fiddly and doesn't always work.)

Answer (score 3):

The man page for systemctl specifically states that `isolate` is dangerous.   This is probably not the best way to restart a single service.  On my system, `graphical.target` has 252 dependencies.  It would probably be better to just reboot the system rather than restart all of those if isolate did what you suggest.

Instead of trying to restart graphical.target, you should find the specific service that supports your graphical interface and use `restart` instead of isolate on that specific service.

You can list all the dependencies with `systemctl list-dependencies graphical.target`  You can list at least some possible display managers with `systemctl list-unit-files '*dm.service'`

Two possible candidates for this would be `lightdm.service` or `gdm.service`.

So, for instance, if it is enabled (and possibly already started) `sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service` would restart your graphical interface.